# How can I make columns in two tables have same width?

Tags: html, css

How can I make columns in two tables have the same width?

I tried applying the `width` property on the `td` element for each column and the property `style = "table-layout: fixed;` but as you can see, the boundaries of the columns do not match.

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/v2bxdygj/

Comment: You have two variants - one is with Javascript, the second is to make it one single table.

Comment: I can not use single table, because the header should be static. That is why I try to combine tables

Comment: You can make it a single table with two sticky rows on the top.

Comment: I can not because sticky rows does not work with `cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport` angular, it works if table is plain

Comment: Okay, so you could either give each column a certain size or use Javascript.

Comment: Could you share an example? What is difference if I set the same widths by JS?

Comment: Post a [mcve] in your question please, not on a third party site

Comment: I believe [CSS grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) is the way to solve your problem with static header and separate table data. I recommend to focus on `grid-template-areas` in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my sample which works to some extent:

```css
table {
        border: 1px solid grey;
        border-collapse:collapse;
        width: 100%;
        table-layout:fixed;
    }
    td {
        border: 1px solid grey; 
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    td span {
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .code {
        width: 40px;    
    }
    .name {
        width: 548px;   
    }
    .colspan {
        width: 588px;   
    }
    .col3, .col4, .col5 {
        width: 10%; 
    }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="code"><button>Код</button></td>
    <td class="name"><button>Название</button></td>
    <td class="col3">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="col4">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="col5">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    
    <td class="colspan" colspan="2"><input type="text"> <span>Фильтр по коду и названию...</span></td>
    <td class="col3">Разрешено</td>
    <td class="col4">Запрещено</td>
    <td class="col5">Неопределено</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="code">1</td>
    <td class="name">Вход в систему</td>
    <td class="col3">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="col4">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="col5">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Редактирование, администрирование групп и пользователей</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Создание или редактирование определения адресного элемента</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>Создание или редактирование записи адресного элемента</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```